# PHP decode strange json-feed

Tags: php, json, curl, foreach, decode

I have a json-feed that looks like this that I need to decode using cURL.

```
"count":836,
"value":{
"title":"AW-rss",
"description":"Pipes Output",
"link":"http:\/\/pipes.yahoo.com\/pipes\/pipe.info?_id=566903fd393811762dc74aadc701badd",
"pubDate":"Tue, 04 Sep 2012 16:33:30 +0000",
"generator":"http:\/\/pipes.yahoo.com\/pipes\/",
"callback":"",
"items":[
{
"title":"Title",
"description":"Description",
"link":"http://",
"category":"Category",
"pubDate":null,
"guid":"14917809",
"author":"Author",
"y:published":null,
"y:id":{
"permalink":"false",
"value":"14917809"
},
"y:title":"title"
},
//and then it continues like that with several more items.
```

This is the code I am using, but I cannot for the life of me get the foreach-loop to give me something substantial.

```
$query = 'http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=566903fd393811762dc74aadc701badd&_render=json';

    $ch = curl_init(); // open curl session

    // set curl options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $query);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
    $result = curl_exec($ch); // execute curl session
    $data = json_decode($result);
    curl_close($ch); // close curl session



    **foreach($data['items'] as $item) {
        $guid['guid']}**
```

As you can see I am trying to get the guid of the items in the feed. Any help would be MUCH appreciated.

var_dump($data); gives:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["count"]=> int(836) ["value"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (7) { ["title"]=> string(6) "AW-rss" ["description"]=> string(12) "Pipes Output" ["link"]=> string(75) "http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=566903fd393811762dc74aadc701badd" ["pubDate"]=> string(31) "Tue, 04 Sep 2012 20:34:56 +0000" ["generator"]=> string(29) "http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/" ["callback"]=> string(0) "" ["items"]=> array(836) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (10) { ["title"]=> string(68) "Noggrann chefsassistent till vÃ¤lkÃ¤nt fÃ¶retag i centrala Stockholm" ["description"]=> string(163) "Har du tidigare erfarenhet av arbete som VD-assistent och Ã¶nskar bli en del av ett av Sveriges stÃ¶rsta fÃ¶retag? DÃ¥ Ã¤r du den som vi sÃ¶ker, ansÃ¶k redan idag!" ["link"]=> string(122) "http://www.academicwork.se/jobbannons/noggrann-chefsassistent-till-valkant-foretag-i-centrala-stockholm/stockholm/14917809" ["category"]=> string(16) "Assistent- enkel" ["pubDate"]=> NULL ["guid"]=> string(8) "14917809" ["author"]=> string(13) "Academic Work" ["y:published"]=> NULL ["y:id"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (2) { ["permalink"]=> string(5) "false" ["value"]=> string(8) "14917809" } ["y:title"]=> string(68) "Noggrann chefsassistent till vÃ¤lkÃ¤nt fÃ¶retag i centrala Stockholm" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#5 (10)
```

and so on.

Comment: Shouldn't `$datas` be `$data` and what's the point of the `$guid['guid']` line?

Comment: Yeah, sorry that was a typo. It is $data. The $guid['guid'] is to get the "guid" of every item in the json. But I'm gonna put it in an array or something. The thing is that the loop doesn't work... And I edited with var_dump($data).

Comment: Shouldn't that be `foreach ($data['value']['items'] as $item)`?

Comment: But then wouldn't foreach ($data['value']['items'] as $item){
     echo $item;
 }
echo an array? The whole page is an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

json_decode returns an object, so you need to treat it slightly different than a plain array.

```
$data = json_decode($result);

$items = $data->{'value'}->{'items'};
$GUID = array();
foreach($items as $obj)
{
  $GUID[] = $obj->{'guid'};
}

var_dump($GUID);
```

I'll note that the json_decode method can convert the return into an array (json_decode($result,true)) if that would help.  Like so:

```
$data = json_decode($result,true);

$items = $data['value']['items'];
$GUID = array();
foreach($items as $obj)
{
  $GUID[] = $obj['title'];
}

var_dump($GUID);
```

Comment: I love you. No, I'm IN love with you. I could tell that this was a stupid question before-hand but I just cannot wrap my head around the json-feeds, it's like my kryptonite. Thanks a million!